# Performance cost of timers

Tags: c#, wpf, performance, timer

I need to optimize an rather big WPF application. We are getting data updates from the domain layer in a very high frequency. One idea to optimize the UI was to delay the update of some UI elements to improve the UI performance. Let's say we have a property "Counter" in the domain model that changes about 100 times per second. So we could create a timer that fires only once a second and updates an corresponding property in our ViewModel when the timer fires. That works pretty good so far. The timer would just copy the value from the domain object to the view model once a second and we're done.

Problem is: Each view model instance represents an entry in a list. And this list could have several thousand entries. With the solution I described we would also create several thousand timers. I would guess that creating so many timer instances is no good idea. A simple solution would be to just create a static timer instance in a base class or somewhere else and just use this single instance to update all view models. But that is not possible either. We have any different properties that should be updated independently from the domain models and each should have an idividual update rate.

Question 1: Does anyone have an idea how expensive a timer is? Does it really matter if I would create many thousand timers?

Question 2: Another soulution would be to create some sort of scheduler ... a kind of "MultiTimer" where I can register multiple timeouts. Does anyone have an suggestion on how to implement something like that?

Comment: Jalal's answer pointed me to a possible solution. I do have very many objects that I need to refresh with a delay. But I propably do not have so many different refresh times. So I could just create a Dictionary containing updaters each one representing a unique update frequency. Each updater would have a timer and a Queue where I can schedule the updates. This way I have only a couple of timers serving my thousands of objects. I'll post a code snippit once I'm done. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

This could be implemented in a more elegant fashion using [Microsoft's Reactive Extensions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/gg577609) - in short Rx. Among other cool functionality Rx contains a Throttle Method that's well suited to tame aggressive event sources. Take a look [here](http://eprystupa.wordpress.com/2009/12/19/throttling-high-frequency-data-feed-using-reactive-extensions-for-net/).

Comment: I would love to use that ... but the decision was NOT to use Rx. So unfortunately that is not an option.

Comment: Whats the reason against RX ?

Comment: It's because it is not "official" part of .Net and there is no source code availabla. So the decision was that is should not be used since we do not have a way to fix possible bugs (that we do not have for official .Net stuff either ... but anyay).

Answer (score 2):

If you "`create many thousand timers`" you will blow up the OS!. The timers callbacks runs in different threads or threadpool, so imagine you are creating a thousand of threads...

However the solution to your problem is depending on how you are getting the data from the domain layer at the first place. more information about that will helps.

**Edit:** You can assign index of update to each of your data changed. if your data is updating frequently in about `100ms` and you want each row to only updates after `1 second`, then use  a `Dictionary` or a `ConcurrentDictionary` that hold each data and its update index `int` "or you can use `DataTime` instead if not all the data updating in `100ms`..":

```
private ConcurrentDictionary<Data, int> _dataUpdateFrequence = new ConcurrentDictionary<Data, int>();
private const int MaxFrequent = 10;

Data data = null;

private void OnDataUpdated(Data data)
{
    int lastUpdateIndex = _dataUpdateFrequence.GetOrAdd(data, 0);
    int newUpdateIndex = (lastUpdateIndex + 1) % MaxFrequent;        

    bool needsUpdate = lastUpdateIndex == 0 || newUpdateIndex == 0;
    if (needsUpdate)
    {
        //Update the UI.
    }
    _dataUpdateFrequence.TryUpdate(data, newUpdateIndex , lastUpdateIndex);
}
```

**Edit2:** You stated at a comment:

> I can not gauaranty that the domain object value is updated constantly. It might change a property 100 times in one second and then never again

In this case I would use `DateTime` instead of `int`, and so check if the last update was larger than 1 second then update the UI, else ignore. but here you need also to define a timer that will update all fields in each `30 second` for example. so no *starvation* to any of your updates "just in case for example some fields update in half a second and never updates again!" So:

```
private const int UpdateAllInterval = 30 * 1000;//30 seconds

private readonly TimeSpan MinimumIntervalToUpdate = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 1);

private ConcurrentDictionary<Data, DateTime> _dataUpdateFrequence = new ConcurrentDictionary<Data, DateTime>();

private System.Timers.Timer _updateTimer = new System.Timers.Timer();


//At the UI Constructor:
public Window..
{
    _updateTimer.Interval = UpdateAllInterval;
    _updateTimer.AutoReset = true;
    _updateTimer.Elapsed += OnUpdateTimerElapced;
    _updateTimer.Start();
}

private void OnUpdateTimerElapced(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    this.Dispatcher.Invoke(/*update the UI method*/);//or this.Invoke if winforms
}

private void OnDataUpdated(Data data)
{
    DateTime currentTime = DateTime.Now;
    DateTime lastUpdateTime = _dataUpdateFrequence.GetOrAdd(data, currentTime);

    bool needsUpdate = lastUpdateTime == currentTime || 
        currentTime > lastUpdateTime.Add(MinimumIntervalToUpdate);
    if (needsUpdate)
    {
        //Update the UI.
    }
    _dataUpdateFrequence.TryUpdate(data, currentTime, lastUpdateTime);
}
```

Comment: The domain model objects are implementing the INotifyPropertyChanged interface and are just raising an PropertyChanged event when the domain data changes. We are (more or less) wrapping each domain object instance into an view model instance. Some of the domain model properties are just mapped to view model properties and some properties are calculated from the domain model data when they change. Does that answer your question?

Comment: Nice ... BUT: If I undertand your solution correctly it rely on constant updates. I can't do that. I have to make sure that the data is refreshed even if no furhter updates are made from the domain object. Your solution would just ignore updates untill the count is hit again. But I can not gauaranty that the  domain object value is updated constantly. It might change a property 100 times in one second and then never again. So I would end up with an old value in this case that never is refreshed to the correct one.

Comment: @harri: then if the time at the server is not frequently changing. then use `DateTime` instead of `int` so when last update to the data  `_dataUpdateFrequence.TryUpdate(data, DateTime.Now, previousTime);`, and so check if the last update was timespan  was larger than `1 second` then update the UI, else ignore. but here you need also to define a timer that will update all fields in each `30` second for example. so no _starvation_ to any of your updates "if for example some field only updates ones"...

Comment: @harri: answer updated "Add code to describe the idea of `DateTime`"

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. That would do. But to be honest I do not like the solution very much because it is to "complex". I do not want an additional timer that triggers the update when there was no update. It just feels like an workaround. 

What I will do is create a Dictionary mapping an update interval to an updater object. Most of the objects in the application will have a 200ms or 500ms update rate, so I would realy only have two entries here. Each updater object will maintain an Queue of objects that should be updated and process this queue in the timer interval.

Comment: @harri: Glad you benefit from the answer :), however if you can _guarantee_ that all object will be updated. then it`s ok to get rid of the "update all timer". otherwise you should leave it there "maybe adjust its interval to more than 30 second lets say 3 minutes", so even if an update occurs just once to an element, we are sure finally it will be updated.

Comment: As I said. Your solution would work. But the reason I'm doing the whole thing is to reduce Load on the UI thread. Instead of havinf thousands of updates per second I want to reduce it to a couple of hundred updates by delaying the updates for a short time (maybe 500ms). All property changes occured in the meantime can safly be ignored. It doen't matter for the user to wait half a second to get the value. But it would certainly matter it he have to wait for 30 seconds or longer in case there is no additional update.

Answer (score 0):

Question1: Timer is always overhead for the existing application.  It eats up the performance, especially your case with many thousand timers.

Question2: You can try Publish-Subscribe model, which is the best fit for your business scenario.

Comment: It was specifically mentioned that the data changes too frequently for the publish-subscribe model to work.